# Unable to Autowire ServiceImpl Class Bean with Service Class Object

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

The error which I'm facing is as follows:

```
    root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginAndSignUpController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.frosters.firststep.service.LoginAndSignUpService com.frosters.firststep.controller.LoginAndSignUpController.loginAndSignUpService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.frosters.firststep.service.LoginAndSignUpService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.frosters.firststep.service.LoginAndSignUpService com.frosters.firststep.controller.LoginAndSignUpController.loginAndSignUpService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.frosters.firststep.service.LoginAndSignUpService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.frosters.firststep.service.LoginAndSignUpService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tried resolving it through using @Component,@Service annotations and has tried defining the bean in XML Configuration as explained in other StackOverflow links but I'm getting the same error. May be I'm not getting it right or I'm doing something wrong.

ControllerClass is as follows:

```
package com.frosters.firststep.controller;

@RequestMapping(value="/login.html")
@Controller
public class LoginAndSignUpController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginAndSignUpService loginAndSignUpService;

    @ModelAttribute("userVO")
    public UserVO createUserVOBean(){
        return new UserVO();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLoginForm(){
        System.out.println("inside getLoginForm() method");
        return new ModelAndView("Login");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView verifyLogin(@ModelAttribute("userVO")UserVO userVO){
        System.out.println("inside verifyLogin");
        boolean result = loginAndSignUpService.verifyUser(userVO);
        ModelAndView model;
        if(!result){
            model = new ModelAndView("Login");
            model.addObject("loginError", "invalid username/password");
        }
        else
            model = new ModelAndView("LoginSuccess"); //temporary view
        return model;
    }

}
```

ServiceImplClass is as follows:

```
package com.frosters.firststep.serviceimpl;

public class LoginAndSignUpServiceImpl implements LoginAndSignUpService{

    @Autowired
    private LoginAndSignUpDAO loginAndSignUpDAO;

    public boolean verifyUser(UserVO userVO) {
        boolean result = loginAndSignUpDAO.validateUser(userVO);
        if(result)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

DAOImpl Class is as follows:

```
package com.frosters.firststep.daoimpl;

public class LoginAndSignUpDAOImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements LoginAndSignUpDAO{

    public boolean validateUser(UserVO userVO) {
        String userName = userVO.getUserName();
        String password = userVO.getPassword();
        SqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource("username", userName);
        try{
        String pass = this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(FSUtils.LOGIN_INFO, paramSource, String.class);
        if(pass != null && !pass.isEmpty()){
            if(pass.equals(password))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex){
        return false;
        }
    }


    }
```

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="3.0">

  <display-name>Login And SignUp</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.frosters.firststep" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml where I've defined the beans:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:DbUtil.properties"/>

        <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.frosters.firststep" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->

        <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.mysql.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.mysql.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.mysql.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.mysql.password}" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="loginAndSignUpDAO" class="com.frosters.firststep.daoimpl.LoginAndSignUpDAOImpl">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="loginAndSignUpService" class="com.frosters.firststep.serviceimpl.LoginAndSignUpServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```

I've tried defining all the beans in spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml also but doing this also doesn't resolve the problem.

someone can please help me to see where the fault? .... Thank you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add ContextCLoaderListener in your web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: @Imran..Thanks but after adding this in my web.xml it's breaking up more.. during the redeployment of war I'm getting more exceptions like:

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
it's unable to create any of the beans now.

Comment: can you post complete stacktrace? And one more thing.. I am not able to find DataSource property in *DaoImpl.. I think that is the error.

Comment: yes, that's because I've used Spring DAO Support and extended the superclass named "NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport " (provided by Spring and as after extending this class you don't have to define namedParameterJdbcTemplate and set a dataSource in it through Autowiring.) and dataSource can be provided through the bean as I provided it the in **ApplicationContext.xml**.
For ref: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOyjFjilPIo&list=PL1A506B159E5BD13E&index=9)

Comment: full stack trace is exceeding the character limit.. so i kept it on github..
you can check those complete stack trace here:
[https://github.com/guptaakashdeep/reflections/blob/master/StackTrace

Comment: The exception is because it is not able to load driver. put "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" instead of "com.mysql.jdbc.driver" in your properties file. Capital D :)

Comment: ohh!! My bad.. and it fixed the issue..!! thanks for your time man!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The Spring component scan, will scan your base package for all beans that are annotated with

- @Repository (for DAO)
- @Component
- @Service (for Service)
- @Controller (for Controller)

Since Spring do not find any annotation for DAOImpl and ServiceImpl, hence it dose not initialize them as a consequences your @Autowired does not work because there are no qualifying candidates.

So add @Repository to your DaoImpl and @Service to your ServiceImpl classes and then try again.

```
package com.frosters.firststep.serviceimpl;

@Service
public class LoginAndSignUpServiceImpl implements LoginAndSignUpService{

    @Autowired
    private LoginAndSignUpDAO loginAndSignUpDAO;

    public boolean verifyUser(UserVO userVO) {
        boolean result = loginAndSignUpDAO.validateUser(userVO);
        if(result)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.frosters.firststep.daoimpl;

@Repository
public class LoginAndSignUpDAOImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements LoginAndSignUpDAO{

    public boolean validateUser(UserVO userVO) {
        String userName = userVO.getUserName();
        String password = userVO.getPassword();
        SqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource("username", userName);
        try{
        String pass = this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(FSUtils.LOGIN_INFO, paramSource, String.class);
        if(pass != null && !pass.isEmpty()){
            if(pass.equals(password))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex){
        return false;
        }
    }


   }
```

Try the following order

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.frosters.firststep" />
```

or

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.frosters.*" />
```

As Imran indicated in his post (which could be the main cause), put the context listener to your web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: @Raf...Thanks for the suggestion but I've tried this before and I was facing the same error and as of now I'm defining beans in **applicationContext.xml**.

Comment: I have had nightmares with Spring at times and Autowiring was not fun. We were using Spring and Hibernate. Anyway, long ago I wrote a spring project for a uni project, have a look in case the configs there be of some help to your case https://github.com/rhamedy/SRPS/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

Comment: I've tried this also but as soon as i'm defining the listener in my web.xml, it's throwing error while redeployment as it's unable to set property for dataSource:
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException
Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.driver]

Comment: any idea why it's not able to get properties from property file after defining the listener?

Comment: If there are many errors in your spring configs, one will throw exception and the compilation terminates. As soon as you fix that error, then compiler will go ahead and check for other errors, that is why when you include the listener in web.xml you get other errors, that does not mean that listener is causing it. Your configs are different than mine (as given in the github link) so copying across won't help you but, look at the structure of how configs are organized there.

Comment: yeah! that i know and i didn't copied it. I just looked on the structure and organised it in the same way as yours as you said.
As ContextLoaderListener reads the spring configuration file (with value given against contextConfigLocation in web.xml) and I've provided the ApplicationContext.xml and spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml under it as context-params and init-param respectively
According to which it should not throw any exception related to this but I'm don't know why it's happening?
and as soon as i remove the listener it deploys perfectly
Autowiring is becoming a nightmare for me also now

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.frosters.firststep" />
```

Should be in applicationContext.xml and not in the spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml.